I can't override a template from amasty store locator with hyva compatibility
I tryed to override two templates from Amasty store locator center.phtml and left.phtml but i dont understand why it's not working i named the module just like in registration.php -> Hyva_AmastyStorelocator.
When i add some tailwind class to add style i see no change.
If someone already have this problem and can help me it's could be very cool thanks :D

You have to override the templates in your theme Amasty_Storelocator.
The override works for me here : app/design/frontend/Mytheme/default/Amasty_Storelocator/templates/left.phtml
And to add viewModel or anything else you can create a app/code module with a module.xml with :
<module name="Vendor_Storelocator">
   <sequence>
       <module name="Amasty_Storelocator" />
   </sequence>
</module>

and registration.php :
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Storelocator',
    __DIR__
);


When you deal with Hyva compatibility module, you need use in your Hyva theme the folder with the name of original module like Amasty_Storelocator, not Hyva_AmastyStorelocator: https://docs.hyva.io/hyva-themes/compatibility-modules/automatic-template-overrides.html#example-scenario
Example:
Template declaration:
Mirasvit_Gdrp::cookie_bar.phtml
Original Module Template:
Mirasvit/Gdpr/view/frontend/templates/cookie_bar.phtml
Compat Module Template:
Hyva/MirasvitGdpr/view/frontend/templates/cookie_bar.phtml
Theme Override:
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Mirasvit_Gdpr/templates/cookie_bar.phtml
